# can not find 404 error with node js request

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am following the directory structure given here:

[angular-fullstack](http://tylerhenkel.com/building-an-angular-node-comment-app-using-yeoman/)

I have a folder name Musician in server/api.

In this folder,

Musician

|

|----->index.js

|----->Musician.controller.js

|----->Musician.model.js

In index.js,

I give the routes as:

```
use strict';

var express = require('express');
var musicians = require('./Musician.controller');
var auth = require('../../auth/auth.service');

var router = express.Router();


    router.get('/musicians', musicians.findAll);
    router.get('/musicians/:id', musicians.findById);
    router.post('/musicians', auth.isAuthenticated(), musicians.add);
    router.put('/musicians/:id', musicians.update);
    router.delete('/musicians/:id', musicians.delete);
    router.get('/import', musicians.import);



    module.exports = router;
```

It gives the error that way. But if I put this in my `routes.js`, It works.

How do I get these routes working right from index.js?

As per the directory structure and articles on web, it should be working from `index.js`.

Error:

[image]

Comment: Is that all of your index.js? What error are you getting exactly? More details  and code would be helpful.

Comment: @MattHerbstritt: Updated

Comment: @MattHerbstritt: Yes, it is the complete index.js in Musicians folder .

Comment: Where do you start your server? I don't see how this could work at all, but I'm not an expert. You need to start your server with an `app.listen(port)` etc. don't you?

Comment: That does not have to be here. It's in app.js.

Comment: What does auth.isAuthenticated() return? Are you sure you sould be calling that function there instead of passing it in as a reference?